# Molecular Gas flow as function of Pressure, Density and Temperature gradients

Tags: flow, gas

In all the flow dynamics textbook I have consulted the gas flow is driven by pressure gradients. Is there a way to analyse a molecular gas flow when also temperature and density gradients exist?

Comment: Yes. But the flow is driven by pressure differences. It is difficult, but there have been work on a mesoscopic description of these things.